# Manually installing Ubuntu on an older desktop

Tags: documentation

I have been trying to install Ubuntu on an older machine, dell dimension e521 with upgraded bios, but the ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso will not install due to the APIC problem. Unfortunately there is no way set noAPIC or APIC=off in the BIOS. This can be a fresh new install. I currently have Debian 9 installed on it with no problems encountered but I would like ubuntu instead.

I have all the resources I need to do what ever I want to this machine. I have multiple hard drives I can use to load packages for install, I can even edit the ISO files.

Here is the problem. I cannot find any way to install the Ubuntu package outside of a boot DVD. I have not found any information on manually running the install from a hard drive, discs drive, or how to properly edit the ISO. To date, all information I have found about this is incorrect.

Is there any way to edit the boot files(grub) to allow booting of the DVD, running the install manually from Debian or another hard drive with the files on?

Comment: Do you mean ACPI? Which problems exactly do you encounter when trying to install Ubuntu? BTW `acpi=off` should only ever be used during installation.

Comment: How old is this PC?  ie: Are you sure that the `amd64` architecture is appropriate and not `i386`?

Comment: If your existing debian stretch has grub installed; you can modify grub to boot an ISO.  I haven't used what I'm suggesting in 5+ years, but I can't see why it wouldn't still work.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot maybe helpful; but you'll need to adjust for debian (which isn't difficult).

Comment: Answer to question one: the error is Kernel panic - not syncing: IO-APIC

Comment: grub can only change the boot process for the current OS installed. It does not control the boot strap process in bios. It will not affect boot from CD.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I have a pretty maxed out dell dimension e521 with 8gb of ram. It was working perfectly up until last week. I think the latest version of Ubuntu 16.0.4.7 uses the APIC stuff and that has messed up my boot. I remember before when this computer ran Ubuntu 18.04. The key to get it running was to use the grub commands

```
noapic acpi_use_timer_override
```